# Print a Complete Transitive Closure Tree

Tags: php, mysql, transitive-closure-table

On our online shop (PHP/MySQL), for our category structure we are using a transitive closure table (ancestor, descendant, length) as described by Bill Karwin.

I am finding it very flexible and useful, but can not work out how to print the complete category tree without recursion. Is this possible?

For example, I want an output similar to:

- Audio

  - Portable

    - MP3
- Computing

  - Optical Drives

    - DVD-RW
  - Input Devices

    - Wireless

      - Keyboards
- Household Appliances
- Televisions

  - LCD

    - Widescreen
  - CRT

Optionally limiting by the total category depth.

Is this a limitation of this model, or is there a way around it? At present I have been using recursion and caching the result.

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is the simplest way to do it - especially if it's for display.

Alternatively you can do it from MySQL along the lings of the advice in this answer [How can I find all siblings to my node and its anchestors in a hierarchical category tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316126/hierarchical-category-select-query-in-mysql)

Comment: I assume you have written a function to do it - if not I can supply one I use for exactly this purpose.